# django import search path

Tags: python, django

I'm configuring autocompletion for python and django in vim.  One of the problems is that I need to set an environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings.  The django tutorial states that

> The value of DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
>   should be in Python path syntax, e.g.
>   mysite.settings. Note that the
>   settings module should be on the
>   Python import search path.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

But if your app isn't in the import search path, how do you make it so that it is?

Comment: Could you please clarify the question? How is the autocompletion in vim related to this? You don't need DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE if you don't actually run the Django framework and even then manage.py will often handle it for you. What is the actual problem caused by the missing environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three choices.

1. Set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include your application's directory.  Be sure it has an `__init__.py` file.
2. Create a `.pth` file in site-packages to point to your application's directory.
3. Install your application in site-packages.

These are the three ways of "installing" a Python module.  Read about the [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) module for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Try appending the path to sys.path at runtime.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/myapp')
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/django/bin`

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/myapp`

Answer (score 0):

import from path containing dir with module (with `__init__.py` file)

example:

```
dm@batman:~/.local/15/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ pwd
/home/d/dm/.local/15/lib/python2.7/site-packages

dm@batman:~/.local/15/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ ls
django  Django-1.5.11-py2.7.egg-info

dm@batman:~/.local/15/lib/python2.7/site-packages $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/home/d/dgaloc/.local/15/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 11, 'final', 0)
```